# Building POCo library with openssl 1.1.1i for windows is failing

Tags: openssl, poco-libraries

I am trying to poco library using my custom built openssl 1.1.1i
I followed the instructions given in https://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-GettingStarted.html

For windows there are 3 options.

1. Use POCO pre-built OpenSSL binaries (simplest and recommended)
2. Build OpenSSL using scripts from POCO distribution package
3. Use a third-party pre-built OpenSSL

Mine belongs to 3rd option

I copied openssl artefacts in %POCO_BASE% folder
Set environment variables for INCLUDE and LIB to point to right path.
But I get following error when I run buildwin script

```
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\CipherKey.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\Cipher.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\CipherFactory.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18      DigestEngine.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18      ECDSADigestEngine.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\CipherKeyImpl.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\CipherImpl.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18      ECKey.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18      ECKeyImpl.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18      EVPPKey.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\CryptoException.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18      KeyPair.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\CryptoStream.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18      KeyPairImpl.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\CryptoTransform.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:18      OpenSSLInitializer.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\DigestEngine.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\ECDSADigestEngine.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19      PKCS12Container.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19      RSACipherImpl.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\ECKeyImpl.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\EVPPKey.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19      RSADigestEngine.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\ECKey.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19      RSAKey.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19      RSAKeyImpl.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\KeyPair.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\KeyPairImpl.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19      X509Certificate.cpp
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\OpenSSLInitializer.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\PKCS12Container.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\RSACipherImpl.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\RSAKey.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\RSAKeyImpl.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\RSADigestEngine.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
build   09-Jun-2021 01:44:19    d:\build-dir\clientsdk-poc-win\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\crypto\include\poco\crypto\crypto.h(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file src\X509Certificate.cpp) [D:\build-dir\CLIENTSDK-POC-WIN\downloaded\windows\poco-1.10.1-all\Crypto\Crypto_vs150.vcxproj]
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What i did to get it works,

1. Download prebuild openssl from [slproweb.com](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)
2. Install it under poco directory like that %POCO_BASE%/OpenSSL
3. With CMake check ENABLE_NET and ENABLE_NETSSL_WIN, uncheck ENABLE_NETSSL

and you will have a compiled libraries works f